# FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer return is null

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I am following Html5rocks tutorial

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

and I am trying to use readAsArrayBuffer instead of readAsBinaryString in slicing a file example (because I want to read gif header to find file resolution). But I am stuck because  evt.target.result (while using readAsBinaryString it is a string)

any ideas?

EDIT : Code

```
reader.onloadend = function(evt) 

{

  if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
    document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
    console.log(evt.target.result.byteLenght)
    document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
        ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
         ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
  }
};

if (file.webkitSlice) {
  var blob = file.webkitSlice(start, stop + 1);
} else if (file.mozSlice) {
  var blob = file.mozSlice(start, stop + 1);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

so in Firefox 13 I get on screen : [object ArrayBuffer]

and on console log : undefined

while in Chromium 18 I get on console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLenght' of null

Comment: Where exactely are you stuck? [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) is the base code. Now, what are your modifications, what did you expect and what goes wrong?

Comment: @RobW I changed reader.readAsBinaryString(blob); to eader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob) and I was expecting to get ArrayBufferbut I get null.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chromium 18: http://jsfiddle.net/XDbnJ/ I see `[object arrayBuffer]`. Include *your* code in the question, including details about your browser and your expectations.

Comment: I can still not reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/XDbnJ/1/. Also, `byteLength` has to be spelled with `th`, not `ht`. Post a full demo using http://jsfiddle.net/ whihc shows your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typing mistake in:

```
console.log(evt.target.result.byteLenght)
```

`byteLenght` should be `byteLength`

Comment: I already mentioned that in the comments. This is not the cause of the problem though: This would just log `undefined`, and not throw a `TypeError`.